# Create dummy variables for every unique value in a column based on a condition from a second column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe that looks kind of like this with many more rows and columns:

```
> df <- data.frame(country = c ("Australia","Australia","Australia","Angola","Angola","Angola","US","US","US"), year=c("1945","1946","1947"), leader = c("David", "NA", "NA", "NA","Henry","NA","Tom","NA","Chris"), natural.death = c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,0),gdp.growth.rate=c(1,4,3,5,6,1,5,7,9))
> df
    country year leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate
1 Australia 1945  David             0               1
2 Australia 1946     NA            NA               4
3 Australia 1947     NA            NA               3
4    Angola 1945     NA            NA               5
5    Angola 1946  Henry             1               6
6    Angola 1947     NA            NA               1
7        US 1945    Tom             1               5
8        US 1946     NA            NA               7
9        US 1947  Chris             0               9
```

I am trying to add x number of new columns, where x corresponds to the number of unique leaders (column leader) satisfying the condition of leader being dead (natural.death==1). In the case of this df, I would expect to get 2 new columns for Henry and Tom, with values of 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 and 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0, respectively. I would preferably have the two new columns called id1 and id2 according to the order of data presented in natural.death. I need to create 69 new columns as there 69 leaders who died, so I am looking for a non-manual method to deal with this.

I already tried loops, if, for, unique, mtabulate, dcast, dummies but I could not get anything work unfortunately.

I am hoping to get:

```
> df <- data.frame(country = c ("Australia","Australia","Australia","Angola","Angola","Angola","US","US","US"), year=c("1945","1946","1947"), leader = c("David", "NA", "NA", "NA","Henry","NA","Tom","NA","Chris"), natural.death = c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,0),gdp.growth.rate=c(1,4,3,5,6,1,5,7,9),
+                  id1=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),id2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
> df
    country year leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate id1 id2
1 Australia 1945  David             0               1   0   0
2 Australia 1946     NA            NA               4   0   0
3 Australia 1947     NA            NA               3   0   0
4    Angola 1945     NA            NA               5   0   0
5    Angola 1946  Henry             1               6   1   0
6    Angola 1947     NA            NA               1   0   0
7        US 1945    Tom             1               5   0   1
8        US 1946     NA            NA               7   0   0
9        US 1947  Chris             0               9   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a crude way to do this

```
df <- data.frame(country = c ("Australia","Australia","Australia","Angola","Angola","Angola","US","US","US"), year=c("1945","1946","1947"), leader = c("David", "NA", "NA", "NA","Henry","NA","Tom","NA","Chris"), natural.death = c(0,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,0),gdp.growth.rate=c(1,4,3,5,6,1,5,7,9))

tmp=which(df$natural.death==1) #index of deaths
lng=length(tmp) #number of deaths

#create matrix with zeros and lng columns, append to df
df=cbind(df,data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=nrow(df),ncol=lng)))
#change the newly added column names
colnames(df)[(ncol(df)-lng+1):ncol(df)]=paste0("id",1:lng)

for (i in 1:lng) { #loop over new columns
   df[tmp[i],paste0("id",i)]=1 #at index i of death and column id+i set df to 1
}

    country year leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate id1 id2
1 Australia 1945  David             0               1   0   0
2 Australia 1946     NA            NA               4   0   0
3 Australia 1947     NA            NA               3   0   0
4    Angola 1945     NA            NA               5   0   0
5    Angola 1946  Henry             1               6   1   0
6    Angola 1947     NA            NA               1   0   0
7        US 1945    Tom             1               5   0   1
8        US 1946     NA            NA               7   0   0
9        US 1947  Chris             0               9   0   0
```

Comment: This has been very helpful for my next line of code, could you please explain what exactly happens in the loop function? I am trying to create 69 more columns based on the 69 id columns you just helped me to create. For the next 69 columns, I would like to add five 1s before the value of natural death, then 0 when the death actually occurs but I need to stay within the group country.  So if all the observations would be for Angola between 1942 and 1950 with the death in 1946, then I would like to get column shift_id1: 1,1,1,1,0 (death),0,0,0,0. Could you possibly help me again, please?

Comment: @ViktoriaDöme That requires a little more work, best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

And an approach with tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(natural.death == 1, 1, 0),
         id = ifelse(is.na(id), 0, id),
         tmp = cumsum(id)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "id",
              names_from = tmp,
              values_from = id,
              values_fill = list(id = 0)) %>% 
  select(-id0)

  country   year  leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate   id1   id2
  <fct>     <fct> <fct>          <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Australia 1945  David              0               1     0     0
2 Australia 1946  NA                NA               4     0     0
3 Australia 1947  NA                NA               3     0     0
4 Angola    1945  NA                NA               5     0     0
5 Angola    1946  Henry              1               6     1     0
6 Angola    1947  NA                NA               1     0     0
7 US        1945  Tom                1               5     0     1
8 US        1946  NA                NA               7     0     0
9 US        1947  Chris              0               9     0     0
```