# Create lead and lag year dummies for regression in R

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

This is an example data frame, where PRE5_id1,POST5_id1, PRE5_id2, POST5_id2 are the variables that I would like to get. I am looking for a lead and lag value which will have five values of 1 in the years before natural death (PRE5) and 5 years after the year of natural death (POST5). I am not sure how to stay within the group of country when creating these PRE and POST variables, in which case the PRE and POST variables go to +5 and -5 only within the same country.

I am planning to do a separate regressions for each ID (there are overall 69 natural deaths in my dataset and hence up to ID69) and to include PRE5 and POST5 for every regression, something like this: lm(gdp.growth.rate~country+year+PRE5_id1+POST5_id1) so if there is anyway to create these PRE and POST dummies in the regression that could also work.

```
> df <- data.frame(country = rep("Angola",length(20)), year=c(1940:1959), leader = c("David", "NA", "NA", "NA","Henry","NA","Tom","NA","Chris","NA","NA","NA","NA","Alia","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), natural.death = c(0,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),gdp.growth.rate=c(1:20),
+                    id1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
+                  id2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
+                  PRE5_id1=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
+                  PRE5_id2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
+                  POST5_id1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
+                  POST5_id2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0))
> df
   country year leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate id1 id2 PRE5_id1 PRE5_id2 POST5_id1 POST5_id2
1   Angola 1940  David             0               1   0   0        0        0        0        0
2   Angola 1941     NA            NA               2   0   0        1        0        0        0
3   Angola 1942     NA            NA               3   0   0        1        0        0        0
4   Angola 1943     NA            NA               4   0   0        1        0        0        0
5   Angola 1944  Henry             0               5   0   0        1        0        0        0
6   Angola 1945     NA            NA               6   0   0        1        0        0        0
7   Angola 1946    Tom             1               7   1   0        0        0        0        0
8   Angola 1947     NA            NA               8   0   0        0        0        1        0
9   Angola 1948  Chris             0               9   0   0        0        1        1        0
10  Angola 1949     NA            NA              10   0   0        0        1        1        0
11  Angola 1950     NA            NA              11   0   0        0        1        1        0
12  Angola 1951     NA            NA              12   0   0        0        1        1        0
13  Angola 1952     NA            NA              13   0   0        0        1        0        0
14  Angola 1953   Alia             1              14   0   1        0        0        0        0
15  Angola 1954     NA            NA              15   0   0        0        0        0        1
16  Angola 1955     NA            NA              16   0   0        0        0        0        1
17  Angola 1956     NA            NA              17   0   0        0        0        0        1
18  Angola 1957     NA            NA              18   0   0        0        0        0        1
19  Angola 1958     NA            NA              19   0   0        0        0        0        1
20  Angola 1959     NA            NA              20   0   0        0        0        0        0
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

After trying one of the answers from below and modified the original df to the following (see below), I get the following output.df (see below):

```
> df <- data.frame(country=c("Angola","Angola","Angola","Angola",
+                            "Angola","Angola","Angola","Angola",
+                            "Angola","Angola","US","US","US","US",
+                            "US","US","US","US","US","US"), 
+                  year=c(1940:1949,1940:1949), 
+                  leader = c("David", "NA", "NA", "NA","Henry","NA",
+                             "Tom","NA","Chris","NA","NA","NA","NA",
+                             "Alia","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), 
+                  natural.death = c(0,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),gdp.growth.rate=c(1:20),
+                    id1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
+                  id2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))

> output.df
          country year leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate id1 id2 id1.PRE
Angola.1   Angola 1940  David             0               1   0   0       0
Angola.2   Angola 1941     NA            NA               2   0   0       1
Angola.3   Angola 1942     NA            NA               3   0   0       1
Angola.4   Angola 1943     NA            NA               4   0   0       1
Angola.5   Angola 1944  Henry             0               5   0   0       1
Angola.6   Angola 1945     NA            NA               6   0   0       1
Angola.7   Angola 1946    Tom             1               7   1   0       0
Angola.8   Angola 1947     NA            NA               8   0   0       0
Angola.9   Angola 1948  Chris             0               9   0   0       0
Angola.10  Angola 1949     NA            NA              10   0   0       0
US.1           US 1940     NA            NA              11   0   0       0
US.2           US 1941     NA            NA              12   0   0       0
US.3           US 1942     NA            NA              13   0   0       0
US.4           US 1943   Alia             1              14   0   1       0
US.5           US 1944     NA            NA              15   0   0       0
US.6           US 1945     NA            NA              16   0   0       0
US.7           US 1946     NA            NA              17   0   0       0
US.8           US 1947     NA            NA              18   0   0       0
US.9           US 1948     NA            NA              19   0   0       0
US.10          US 1949     NA            NA              20   0   0       0
          id1.POST id2.PRE id2.POST
Angola.1         0       0        0
Angola.2         0       0        1
Angola.3         0       0        1
Angola.4         0       0        1
Angola.5         0       0        1
Angola.6         0       0        1
Angola.7         0       0        0
Angola.8         1       0        0
Angola.9         1       0        0
Angola.10        1       0        0
US.1             0       1        0
US.2             1       1        0
US.3             1       1        0
US.4             1       0        0
US.5             1       0        1
US.6             1       0        1
US.7             0       0        1
US.8             0       0        1
US.9             0       0        1
US.10            0       0        0
```

Comment: Would there by only one 1 in `id1` and `id2` for each `country` ?

Comment: Yes, each ID has a single value of 1. Like shown here in my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135747/create-dummy-variables-for-every-unique-value-in-a-column-based-on-a-condition-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using base R. We create a function `generate_dummy` which returns two columns for each `"id"` column with PRE and POST data.

```
generate_dummy <- function(x) {
   inds <- which(x == 1)
   if(length(inds) == 1) {
     vec <- seq_along(x)
     data.frame(PRE = +(vec > (inds - 6) & vec < (inds)),
               POST = +(vec > (inds) & vec < (inds + 6)))
     }
     else  data.frame(PRE = rep(0, length(x)),POST = rep(0, length(x)))
}


#Columns which start with id
cols <- grep("^id", names(df), value = TRUE)
```

To apply it for each country we split the data by country and apply `generate_dummy` function to each one of them and combine the results.

```
output <- cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$country), function(x) 
                       do.call(cbind, lapply(x[cols], generate_dummy)))))
row.names(output) <- NULL  

output
#   country year leader natural.death gdp.growth.rate id1 id2 id1.PRE id1.POST id2.PRE id2.POST
#1   Angola 1940  David             0               1   0   0       0        0       0        0
#2   Angola 1941     NA            NA               2   0   0       1        0       0        0
#3   Angola 1942     NA            NA               3   0   0       1        0       0        0
#4   Angola 1943     NA            NA               4   0   0       1        0       0        0
#5   Angola 1944  Henry             0               5   0   0       1        0       0        0
#6   Angola 1945     NA            NA               6   0   0       1        0       0        0
#7   Angola 1946    Tom             1               7   1   0       0        0       0        0
#8   Angola 1947     NA            NA               8   0   0       0        1       0        0
#9   Angola 1948  Chris             0               9   0   0       0        1       1        0
#10  Angola 1949     NA            NA              10   0   0       0        1       1        0
#11  Angola 1950     NA            NA              11   0   0       0        1       1        0
#12  Angola 1951     NA            NA              12   0   0       0        1       1        0
#13  Angola 1952     NA            NA              13   0   0       0        0       1        0
#14  Angola 1953   Alia             1              14   0   1       0        0       0        0
#15  Angola 1954     NA            NA              15   0   0       0        0       0        1
#16  Angola 1955     NA            NA              16   0   0       0        0       0        1
#17  Angola 1956     NA            NA              17   0   0       0        0       0        1
#18  Angola 1957     NA            NA              18   0   0       0        0       0        1
#19  Angola 1958     NA            NA              19   0   0       0        0       0        1
#20  Angola 1959     NA            NA              20   0   0       0        0       0        0
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(country = rep("Angola",length(20)), year=c(1940:1959), 
       leader = c("David", "NA", "NA", "NA","Henry","NA","Tom","NA","Chris","NA",
       "NA","NA","NA","Alia","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"), 
      natural.death = c(0,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
      gdp.growth.rate=c(1:20),
      id1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
      id2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but the POST part is doing something weird after I changed half of the dataset to a different country. It adds way more 1 values than 5, although I cannot really see the pattern how. Do you have any idea how I could change that? The PRE value seems to be adding only five values of 1.

Comment: @ViktoriaDöme Not sure either why it behaves in that manner. Do you have an example to reproduce the issue since this seems to work on the sample data you have provided.

Comment: I modified my OP above because I am not sure where else to share the modified dataset with you. Sorry if this is the wrong way of doing this.

Comment: @ViktoriaDöme No..that is correct way of sharing data. For the updated data that you have shared if you see for `Angola` there are only 3 rows remaining for that country hence you get only 3 1's in `POST`. Same goes for `PRE` values in `US`. What output would you expect in such case?

Comment: If you check id1.POST for example, the first three 1 values in the column are correct, but then there are five 1 values which I would like to get rid off. For id2.POST, it is the first five 1 values that I would like to get rid off and the last five 1 values are correct. So overall there should be only five 1s in the whole column and this is the case for PREs but not POST, somehow.

Comment: @ViktoriaDöme yes, because there is no 1 in some id's. I have updated the answer, can you try with updated `generate_dummy` function.